# Game theory tables

Tags: table-of-contents, multicolumn, multirow, extreme-tables

I would like to reproduce these tables in latex. 
Unfortunately whenI'm going to write them, they are horrible. 
They are tables to represent a case of game theory.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is my tentative solution for the first:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Pilot              & Move & Performance   & Cost   \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{A} & 1    & $eq_{1} = 42$ & \Delta t_{p} = 2  \\ \cline{2-4} 
                   & 2    & $eq_{2} = 44$ & 2\Delta t_{p} = 4 \\ \cline{2-4} 
                   & 3    & $eq_{3} = 42$ & \Delta t_{p} = 2  \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{B} & 1    & $eq_{1} = 42$ & \Delta t_{p} = 2  \\ \cline{2-4} 
                   & 2    & $eq_{2} = 44$ & 2\Delta t_{p} = 4 \\ \cline{2-4} 
                   & 3    & $eq_{3} = 42$ & \Delta t_{p} = 2  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: I think it will look neater with fewer horizontal and vertical lines. If you need to divide it up, maybe use gray coloured boxes with white boundaries so that it is easier for the eye to see what lies in what box. The lines look too similar to the text.

Comment: Your code doesn't work, and if it would work, it would generate a completely different table that shown above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution for your first table. It uses the `tabularray` package, which is very well suited for this kind of table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand{\lbf}{\large\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={|c|c|c|c|},hlines,
    cell{2}{1}={r=2}{font=\lbf},cell{4}{1}={r=2}{font=\lbf}}
Player & Action            & Cost      & Effectiveness \\ \hline
 S     & D (detailed scan) & $c_D = 2$ & $ b_D = 1 $    \\
       & Q (quick scan)    & $c_Q = 1$ & $ b_Q = 1 $    \\  
 A     & F (fast mode)     & $c_F = 1$ & $ b_F = -1 $   \\
       & C (cautious mode) & $c_C = 2$ & $ b_C = 1 $    \\  
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First (wee bit variation of  @Pieter van Oostrum nice answer, +1) and second table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand{\lbf}{\large\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{First table}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={c l *{2}{Q[l, mode=math]}},
             cell{2}{1}={r=2}{font=\lbf},
             cell{4}{1}={r=2}{font=\lbf},
             row{1} = {mode=text, c}
             }
Player & Action            & Cost      & Effectiveness \\ 
    \hline
 S     & D (detailed scan) & c_D = 2 &  b_D = 1     \\
       & Q (quick scan)    & c_Q = 1 &  b_Q = 1     \\
 A     & F (fast mode)     & c_F = 1 &  b_F = -1    \\
       & C (cautious mode) & c_C = 2 &  b_C = 1     \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{Second table}
\begin{tblr}{hline{3-Z}=solid, vline{3-Z}=solid,
             colspec={c c *{2}{Q[l, mode=math]}},
              row{1-2} = {mode=text, c}
             }
\SetCell[c=2, r=2]{c}
    &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    Player A
                                &                       \\
    &   &           F           &       C               \\
\SetCell[r=4]{c}    Player S
    &\SetCell[r=2]{c}  D 
        & P_{r_n} - c_D + b_D   & P_{r_c} - c_D + b_D   \\
    &   & P_{r_n} - c_F + b_D   & P_{r_c} - c_C + b_C   \\
    &\SetCell[r=2]{c}  Q
        & P_{r_n} - c_Q + b_D   & P_{r_c} - c_Q + b_Q   \\
    &   & P_{r_n} - c_F + b_D   & P_{r_c} - c_C + b_C   \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]